# How to enter the checked in a $ .each?

Tags: jquery, loops, each, checked

I have a loop in jquery (`$.each`) that creates a list of checkboxes.

I'm trying to insert the `checked`:

```
$.each(arrIdReg, function (id, IdRegx) {
    if (IdRegx[0] == IdRegy[0]) {                 
        Nom = Nom + IdRegx[1] + ", ";
        // strChecked = "checked='checked'";
        strChecked = true;
    }
});
$('#Elen').append("<li><input type='checkbox' value='" + IdRegx[0] + " name='IdReg' class='checkbox'>" + IdRegx[1] + "</li>").prop('checked', strChecked);
```

The problem is that it does not work, because they are all selected.

Can You help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I cant see where you are passing IdRegy, so what are you comparing to

Comment: Did you copy the code correctly? The `append` call isn't inside the loop, so the variable `IdRegx` is not in scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `.append()` is the element you appended to, so your code is trying to set the `checked` property on `$("#Elen")`, not the checkbox.

The simplest way would be to add the `checked` attribute in the HTML that you're appending.

```
$.each(arrIdReg, function (id, IdRegx) {
    if (IdRegx[0] == IdRegy[0]) {                 
        Nom = Nom + IdRegx[1] + ", ";
        var strChecked = "checked='checked'";
    } else {
        strChecked = "";
    }
    $('#Elen').append("<li><input type='checkbox' value='" + IdRegx[0] + " name='IdReg' class='checkbox' " + strChecked + ">" + IdRegx[1] + "</li>");
});
```

If you want to do it more programmatically, you can create the checkbox as a separate step.

```
$.each(arrIdReg, function (id, IdRegx) {
    if (IdRegx[0] == IdRegy[0]) {                 
        Nom = Nom + IdRegx[1] + ", ";
        var boolChecked = true;
    } else {
        boolChecked = false;
    }
    var checkbox = $("<input>", {
        type: 'checkbox',
        value: IdRegx[0],
        name: 'IdReg',
        'class': 'checkbox',
        checked: boolChecked
    });
    $('#Elen').append($("<li>").append(checkbox).append(IdRegx[1]));
});
```

Comment: Hello Bartender,
I tried with your first solution.
But ... just select the last field. The first do not select.

Comment: Can you add `arrIdReg` and `IdRegy` to your question? Or make a fiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Barman, thank you!
Now it works well. It was just my distraction.